# SCSS multiple selectors

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Hi i have this code:

```
.navbar .nav-pills .active > a {  
  background-color: $NavBgHighlight;  
  color: $NavTxtColor;  
}    
.navbar .nav-pills .active > a:hover {  
  background-color: $NavBgHighlight;  
  color: $NavTxtColor;  
}
```

I wanted to merge both of the sections into one section, something more like:

```
 .navbar .nav-pills .active > a, a:hover {  
  background-color: $NavBgHighlight;  
  color: $NavTxtColor;  
}
```

But it doesnt work that way :( how can i merge both of them? ( I want that the :hover and the normal a will act the same)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [SASS selector nesting](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3):

```
.navbar .nav-pills .active {
    > a, > a:hover {
        background-color: $NavBgHighlight;  
        color: $NavTxtColor;  
    }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.navbar .nav-pills .active > a, .navbar .nav-pills .active > a:hover {
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.navbar{
        &.nav-pills{
           &.active {
              > a, > a:hover {
                background-color: $NavBgHighlight;  
                color: $NavTxtColor;  
              }
            } 
          }
        }
```